# Can a wcf client handle 2 version of a SOAP response from the same url?

Tags: web-services, wcf, wsdl

I imported a service reference to a SOAP web service from the customer and coded my client based on that.

After going to production, they said they will launch a new version of the web service with changes to the output type of one of the requests I make to the service (among new messages that I don't consume).

I know I can update my service reference and update my client code to process the updated wsdl and launch an update to my client at the same time the web service updates.

But, is it possible to instrument the WCF code in some way so that I can handle both versions of the response without having to coordinate the update of my client with the update of the web service?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, NO. It depends on what has changes in the service interface? In most cases you'll need (and want) to upgrade your client. You can always ask them to support more versions of their interfaces.